# Firebase authentication on React Native auth.tenandId error

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying a email-password authentication with Firebase. I initiated a web app on Firebase followed the Get Started section of web. But I'm getting this error from `catch()`:

> [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'auth.tenantId')]

My Firebase config:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "spotifymockrn.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "spotifymockrn",
  storageBucket: "spotifymockrn.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

My SignUp Screen where I call `handleFirebase` function when SignUp is pressed.Normally use is also saved with AsyncStorage but for simplicity I'm trying like this now:

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import auth from '../../../../firebase/firebase'
.
.
const handleFirebase = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then(response => { console.log(response.user); })
      .catch((error) => (console.error(error)));
  }
```

I'm getting email, and password from redux store, but I also tried directly writing strings there and got the same error and couldn't find anything online. I tried writing real emails as well as random strings nothing changes. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import auth from '../../../../firebase/firebase'
```

This import would be an object `{ auth, db }` but you need to pass the Firebase Auth instance in `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`. Try changing your import as shown below:

```
// the { }
import { auth, db } from '../../../../firebase/firebase'
```

Now `auth` will be the Auth instance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explainitive answer. It solved my problem and taught me something!